# PDF.js able to create pdf file or PDF.js is just a function to let PDF file display on web broswer?

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

this is PDF.js site

```
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js
```

I m searching and reading a lot of article, most all the coding are import the pdf into `pdf.js` and display on browser, i cannot understand is it PDF.js able to create pdf format and display on web browser without download the PDF file?

this is the sample code i have found :

```
'use strict';

//
// Fetch the PDF document from the URL using promises
//
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
  // Using promise to fetch the page
  pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    //
    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    //
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    //
    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    //
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    page.render(renderContext);
  });
});
```

if PDF.js able to create pdf file , and get the data from MySQL database generate a table display on PDF, how is it work?

Comment: PDF.js does not create a PDF, it displays/consumes already created PDF file/data in binary form.

Comment: @async5 please reply as answer, i will mark as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDF.JS is only a viewer for PDF documents but you can try jsPDF to do this which is also a open source javascript library

http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/